# Need to debug CGI executable under IIS

Tags: delphi, iis, cgi

I need to debug a Delphi created CGI executable that I'm running via IIS. I've followed [this](http://paul.klink.id.au/Software/Delphi/DebuggingIsapiWithIisExpress.htm) very useful tutorial to setup iisExpress run the exe, but I need to trace my execution through my program when I send a particular SOAP message to it. All the examples I've seen so far involve having the IDE kick off iisexpress and then my exe, but that doesn't provide me the ability to send the SOAP request to it which is where my issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, CGI exe's are called with the HTTP header fields in the environment variables, and any data posted in the request ready to fetch over the standard-in handle. These are both possible with Windows API's `CreateProcess`, or even with a little shell script.

Comment: Is there any easy way to capture those env variables/stdin so I can replay it back with a script?

Comment: Write a tiny exe that calls `GetEnvironmentStrings` and writes it to a file? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx